# jQuery hover showing multiple popups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover

I am trying to show a popup using hover in jquery but when i hover over an element, it shows multiple popups and when i remove the mouse from over the element, the popup still stays. Here is the code-

```
var channels = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "goldglove", "terakilobyte", "beohoff", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "syndicate", "riotgames", "comster404", "test_channel", "cretetion", "sheevergaming", "TR7K", "OgamingSC2", "syndicate"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  getChannels();

});

function getChannels() {
  channels.forEach(function(channel) {
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + channel + '?callback=?', function(data) {
      if (data.stream === null) {
        html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><a href=https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel + ' class="result" id="' + channel + '">' + channel + '</a></div><div class="col-md-3">Offline</div></div>';
      } else if (data.stream === undefined) {
        html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><a href=https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel + ' class="result" id="' + channel + '">' + channel + '</a></div><div class="col-md-3">Not Available</div></div>';
      } else {
        html = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><a href=https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel + ' class="result" id="' + channel + '">' + channel + '</a></div><div class="col-md-3">Online</div></div>';
      }
      $("#list").append(html);
      $(".result").hover(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('id');
        var y = "#" + x;
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + x + '?callback=?', function(info) {
          console.log(x);
          detail = '<div id="detail"><img src="' + info.logo + '" class="logo"><p>Language:' + info.language + '</p><p>Mature Content:' + info.mature + '</p><p>Title:' + info.game + '-' + info.status + '</p></div>';
          $(y).append(detail);
        });
      }, function() {
        $("#detail").remove();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I am not able to figure out the problem here. Please help.

Comment: You have an event handler inside a loop, it's attached multiple times

Comment: Yeah, i tried putting that outside the loop, but it doesnt work at all after that.

Comment: I guess I'll have to fix it for you then... give me a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the event handler only once, not multiple times in a loop.
To do that, you could just delegate.

I also cleaned up your code, got rid of the strings of HTML, and used jQuery to create the elements etc.

```
var channels = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "goldglove", "terakilobyte", "beohoff", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "syndicate", "riotgames", "comster404", "test_channel", "cretetion", "sheevergaming", "TR7K", "OgamingSC2", "syndicate"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var self = this;

            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + x + '?callback=?', function(info) {
                var detail = $('<div />', {
                        id: 'detail'
                    }),
                    image = $('<img />', {
                        src: info.logo,
                        'class': 'logo'
                    }),
                    p1 = $('<p />', {
                        text: 'Language:' + info.language
                    }),
                    p2 = $('<p />', {
                        text: 'Mature Content:' + info.mature
                    }),
                    p3 = $('<p />', {
                        text: 'Title:' + info.game + '-' + info.status
                    });

                $(self).append(detail.append(image, p1, p2, p3))
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $("#detail").remove();
        }
    }, '.result');

    channels.forEach(function(channel) {
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + channel + '?callback=?', function(data) {
            var text = data.stream === null ? 'Offline' : data.stream === undefined ? 'Not Available' : 'Online';

            var row = $('<div />', {
                    'class': 'row'
                }),
                col = $('<div />', {
                    'class': 'col-md-3'
                }),
                a = $('<a />', {
                    'class': 'result',
                    href: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channel,
                    id: channel,
                    text: channel
                });

            $("#list").append(row.append(col.append(a)));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank for the help, the previous problem is solved but it is still shows multiple popups if i rapidly hover over multiple elements.

Comment: That's probably because you're doing an ajax request inside the event handler, so it takes a little time before the resulting HTML appears. If the mouse leaves before the content appears, it's not removed because the `remove()` was called before there was anything to remove etc.  What you should be doing is loading the content into the elements, and just hiding and showing them on mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: OK, i will try that, thanx.